# CrudRepository cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, repository

I'm working on a Spring Boot project (generated by Spring Initializr), using Maven. I want to create a CrudRepository, but I'm getting the error "CrudRepository cannot be resolved to a type" and the package org.springframework.data.repository does not contain the CrudRepository class. I tried to follow a bunch of tutorials to understand what is wrong and I didn't find anything. My POM looks right to me, I don't have any build failure when I run maven clean and package goals, I tried to update the project and download sources, but nothing works. Eclipse can't find the CrudRepository class.

Here is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myquickstart</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringQuickstart</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringQuickstart</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And my repository:

```
package com.myquickstart.repositories;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import com.myquickstart.entities.Movie;

@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends CrudRepository<Movie, Long> {

}
```

Thanks for your help

**Edit:**

I've updated the project with the "Maven => Update project" in Eclipse. After that, I got this error in the "Problems" view:

```
C:/Users/carrm/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.11.Final/hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar' in project 'SpringQuickstart' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

I'm not sure to know how to solve this/what is the link with my CrudRepository problem.

Comment: how did you update the project?

Comment: I used the "Maven => Update project" in Eclipse

Comment: How do you get this working on Visual Code Studio, just cant find the extension for "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

Comment: @Siddharth What do you mean? They are Maven dependencies, you don't need a specific IDE to work with Maven. I don't know  if there are Maven plugins for VS Code, but you can always use command lines.

Comment: Just forgot to run `gradle build`. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it was an issue with Maven libraries. I deleted the whole content in `.m2/repository` and ran `Maven > Update project` in Eclipse, so that Maven had to download the whole content again. No more error after this!

**Edit**

As pointed out by *user3578953*, executing maven-clean does the same thing that I did by deleting the whole m2 repository content. I didn't know much about Maven when I first asked this question, but this is obviously a better way to solve the issue.

Answer (score 49):

P.S - I know the original answer used interface not class. But as we can't ask same question again. The answer is for beginner who may missed the interface part.

We generally get this type of error when we create the repository as class instead of interface. CrudRepository is an interface, you most probably extend it using an interface only:

Wrong (Some times when we create the repository we create a class by mistake ):

```
 public class MovieRepository extends CrudRepository<Movie, Long>
```

> Error: CrudRepository cannot be resolved to a type

Just changed it to **interface**:

```
public interface MovieRepository extends CrudRepository<Movie, Long>
```

Comment: You might want to read again the question as I already had an interface and not a class. The issue was something else (check the validated answer).

Comment: You are correct, as you defined it as interface and cleaning up maven repository helps. But the "CrudRepository cannot be resolved to a type" error comes for the above reason as well.The answer is more towards the other users who may have missed to declare it as an interface. My answer is based on the error.

Comment: Can't believe I wasted half hour for this mistake, creating pom again, updating, cleaning project, restarting eclipse, etc. Not sure, if this error comes up in other IDEs out there too, because this seems very misguided.

Answer (score 9):

If you are having this problem, check if the org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository import is working. If it is then this answer probably won't be the solution. If it is not working and the "data" part is highlighted, then check your pom.xml and if you don't have it already, add the following dependency to it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

After adding the dependency, delete your local .m2 directory and build from the command-line. You may also want to reimport the maven project to your workspace.

Comment: This answer helped me !

Answer (score 2):

check mavendependencies for spring-data-jpa-...RELEASE.jar if it contains CrudRepository.class under org.springframework.data.jpa.repository package.

If the class file is there, just maven->update project and run->maven-clean.

If the class file is not there, just search the package in mvnrepository.com.

Comment: You're right about the `maven-clean` since it does the same thing that I did with my ten little fingers by then (I'll edit my answer with that information), but I'm not sure about the relevance of the rest of your answer, or at least with the way you wrote it. It might be a problem of version since I didn't specify any, but I guess that CrudRepository has been there for a long time and isn't a new thing in spring-data-jpa (correct me if I'm wrong). Then, Maven dependencies resolution would get a recent enough version to have this class anyway.

Comment: I had the same issue with a spring boot initializer project. I checked org.springframework.data.jpa. It did not contain the CrudRepository.class. I tried to re-include that dependency, but the error persisted. So I deleted all maven repository, and re-downloaded all, which solved the problem. I didnot specify a version for spring-data-jpa, as it is already there for a while. I still don't know exactly what caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

All seems nice with your dependencies, please try next variants:

1. build project with Maven from command line(`$ mvn spring-boot:run`)
2. In Eclipse IDE: `right click on project-Maven-update project`

Comment: I did the 2nd variant before posting my question ; I tried the 1st one but it doesn't work either. I've edited my post with the error resulting from the "Update project" tool

Answer (score 1):

Add JPA dependency when creating your project. Worked for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, just delete all .m2 content and re-import Maven. it works!

Comment: I don't see what your answer adds that could be more helpful than the validated answer. I answered my own question one year ago with the same solution, and I edited it a couple of weeks ago with a cleaner way to achieve the same thing. Looks like a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i got the message to disappear:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wasn't able to import CrudRepository

to Resolve this

**1. Using Intellij idea**

1. type "extends CrudRepository" click on CrudRepository and press Alt and Enter
2. Click add maven dependency
3. Select CrudRepository

**2. Adding dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Sometimes**
(after adding dependency) you will get an error, importing org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
then add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -3):

`CrudRepository` is an interface not a class. Replace `extends` with `implements`.

Comment: That's wrong. Interfaces extend other interfaces. They do not implement them.

Comment: As Markus said!